# disable list items in ListView

Tags: android, listview, listitem

I wanna `disable all list items` in a `ListView` excluding the 1st position item.

That means every time the 1st item can be clicked not the all.

How can I do this. Is there any way.
Give me some sample code.

Answer (score 2):

I got my answer. only I have to use two override methods in custom adapter,

```
 @Override

    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Does not work if items contain clickable views (button, edittexts etc.) inside them

Answer (score 1):

```
<ListView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" />


    ListView lv = ...

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long arg3) {

       if(position == 1)
       {
         view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
       }

  }
});
```

Comment: i want to make disable. Like if u click on particular item then that listitem color changed. But I dont want that, color should not be changed.

Comment: Only 1st item color must change?

Comment: i did that, but color is changing for all including 1st item. Only event is working for 1st item. But colour changes for all. I dont want that.

Comment: Also try this tutorial Part1 - http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-listview-tutorial-part-1 and Part2 - http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-listview-tutorial-part-2

Comment: I think u didnt get my question.  I am telling for item pressed color, not the color of item. For every view like button, image button  if u click on that , then after pressing some color came then it became as it is.  Did u see that?

Comment: view.setBackgroundDrawable(d); d - is selector - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html

Answer (score 0):

here you have to create custom adapter from listView items and use different color for first item and rest of the items in getView method of custom adapter then the disable click event of other items excluding first position

Comment: So in getView Method of your custom adapter set background of first item to color of your choice

Comment: When i click ListItem how can i display CustomDialog With ListItems